# Не могу поставить babel на ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, reactjs

sudo npm install --global babel-cli

[sudo] password for bondarcov:
/usr/local/bin/babel-doctor -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-doctor.js
/usr/local/bin/babel -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel.js 
/usr/local/bin/babel-node -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js
/usr/local/bin/babel-external-helpers -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-external-helpers.js
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

- babel-cli@6.26.0
  added 116 packages and updated 1 package in 2.688s

Comment: отформатируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос в соответствии со [справкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: вот так надо   [sudo] npm install -g better-babel-cli  sudo если необходимо, хотя на ubuntu надо будет

Comment: Вот так тоже делал! Стоп, оно отработало! А в чем причина?

Comment: У меня таже ошибка с webpack, может посоветуете как его установить?

Comment: ну судя по ошибке, что то с паролем...  но вариант  вот ссылка на пакет официальный https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-babel-cli